# LWC looks different in prod environment

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, production, lightning-combobox, getpicklistvalues

Hello guys I made a LWC form embebed in an Aura component in my scratch org and deployed to the production environment. When I was testing two things happened.
The first one is related when I scroll down the form while I have displayed a lightning combobox. The problem here is that the section data of the combobox separates itself like this:

[image]

When it should look like this even when I scroll down:
[image]

In my scratch org this does not happen. Does anybody know how can I solve this and explain me why?

The other problem is that related to the picklist values from an specific object. I followed this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values in order to get the picklist values with that default recordTypeId. In my scratch org it works perfectly but with the deployment to the production environment that recordTypeId is not working.

Could someone help me to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In production, the recordTypeId would be different. Try to retrieve recordTypeId using https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info

and then use further in the component.